# responsive iframe: scale vs cropping

Tags: html, css

The main issue is my iframe is sometimes not fitting in the space allotted to it depending on the display size. One way I have approached it is trying to wrap a div around an iframe to achieve that responsive rendering. Here is the HTML portion:

```
<div class="resif"><iframe style="border:0px;" src="link" width="700px" height="350px"></iframe></div>
```

Then I have the following style rules:

```
.resif {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom:55%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

.resif iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The result was troubling for me. The iframe was not scaled to fit the containing area as one would expect with the `width:100%;` rule. The iframe appeared too large and went out of screen. I then started to tinker with it and tried other values like 90% or 80% to see what would happen. When I tried smaller percentages, what happened was it would simply crop the iframe; everything to the right of that percentage would be cut off.

I also tried directly setting `width:100%` in the iframe's properties, but again no luck

### Question

Why is the div wrap approach I have tried above not working? Is it not feasible to scale an iframe to fit an area; currently it seems I can at best crop out certain parts of it -- which doesn't solve anything unfortunately.

For what it's worth, I have used this approach successfully in the past when embedding a video. The video iframe was rendered responsively on different display sizes, but with the iframe something seems to be different or my intuition is flawed, in which case I'd like to see how to fix the above code. Alternatively, feel free to post a different solution if this approach looks to be a lost cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is here with this ***width="700px" height="350px"*** on your ***iframe*** element, try this :

```
.resif iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100% !important;
  height:auto !important;
```

}

or this :

```
.resif iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
```

}